# Why do I have to return pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I tried to write an function that sorts arrays using pointers. My **p** pointer points to **x** array but why should I return **x** as a pointer?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int sort(int x[], int n){
    int *p,k;
    p=x;
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int l=i+1; l<n; l++){
            if(*(p+i)>*(p+l)){
                k=*(p+i);
                *(p+i)=*(p+l);
                *(p+l)=k;
            }
        }
    }
    return *x;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    sort(a,n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why *are* you returning anything?  You don't use it.

Comment: No, you are throwing it away.  if it was something like ret = sort(a,n) you would be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function returns an `int` (value), not a pointer. your implementation (`return *x;`) returns the first element of parameter `x[]` by value.

> why should I return x as a pointer?

what is the return value supposed to indicate? it's not clear why you would return anything in this scenario. until you can answer that, `void` would be better.

Comment: @filemonster that's because `x[]` is passed as a pointer to `sort`. the array is by reference. `sort` is mutating the array: `int a[n];`.

Comment: I'm new to pointers so I didn't make the use of pointers in this. I should not return anything right? once sorting function runs, it changes the array in main function.

Comment: @filemonster exactly. note: in C, `int x[]` is like `int* x` (there's your pointer)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to why you “have to” return a pointer is that you clearly don't have to return anything. You are *not* returning pointer (but an `int`) and you are not using the returned value for anything. You can change function's return type to `void` and remove the line with `return` and it will work just as well.

The reason why it works without returning anything is that you are passing a pointer to the array `a` as *argument* to `sort` and then modifying the array — known as `x` inside that function – in place. So there is only one array, and thus you don't have to return another one, or a pointer thereto, for the changes to be visible in `main`.